# Converting a String to a float and assigning that float as a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that has `'word'\t'num'\n` as a string.  I would like to convert it to a dictionary which I have done except how to a convert the value 'num' to a floating point number, so that the dict is of this format `{word : num} and the num is not a string but a floating point number.

Here is my script so far:

```
file_stream = open(infile)
file_list = file_stream.readlines()
dict_output = {}
for line in file_list:
    tmp = line.split()
    dict_output[tmp[0]] = float(tmp[1])
```

If I remove the `float()` the script runs fine and it creates a dictionary with the values as strings.  When I try to cast the string as an int I get the error message:
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: stand"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting values to floats correctly.

However, you have at least *one* line where the is more than just a tab character on the line or the second value is *not* a float. Try changing your code to:

```
key, value = line.rsplit('\t', 1)
try:
    dict_output[key] = float(value)
except ValueError:
    print 'Unexpected line: {!r}'.format(line)
```

This splits the line on just the last `\t` tab character instead of on any whitespace. This leaves lines that may have *multiple* tabs on one line intact and assumes that only the last value is a float.

If this still fails, the code prints out the problem line to show us what else we may need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Because your format is : `word'\t'num'\n` so between word and num is `t` (tab). you should change from `line.split()` to `line.split('\t'). So, full code should be:

```
file_stream = open(infile)
file_list = file_stream.readlines()
dict_output = {}
for line in file_list:
    tmp = line.split('\t')
    dict_output[tmp[0]] = float(tmp[1])
```

Comment: This answer was correct as well, the answer I choose was posted before yours so I had already fixed the error.